# Flutter: Dart language is not showing up when creating a new project in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, dart, intellij-plugin

Disclaimer: I'm extremely new to this stuff; I'm trying out app development for the first time so please acknowledge that before flaming me if I'm missing something obvious lol.

So I've just started watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ukSR1GRtMU&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9jLYyp2Aoh6hcWuxFDX6PBJ&pp=iAQB) tutorial series on Flutter that uses Android Studio as the IDE. I've installed the Flutter plugin aswell as the Dart plugin but for some reason when I try to create a new project, Dart is missing from the available languages:

[Clicking the plus button on the side of the available languages panel will give me more lang plugins that I need to install to operate (dart not being one of them).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhdhA.png)

[Also, theres a Dart generator on the left:It just shows me this. I've messed around a bit with that directory up there but it keeps saying that the relevant file wasn't found, even though I have the Dart plugin installed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTfO4.png)

I've done a few google searches and looking at my installed plugins in Android Studio, the Dart plugin is there and installed along with Flutter. I also tried looking for other tutorials but odd things here and there in the structure of the tutorials along with the Android Studio structure and UI have changed and I'd like to be able to stick to the series I found.

Any help is appreciated and I apologize if this is a noob thing to ask.

Comment: Your first screenshot looks fine - you wouldn't expect to see Dart there. In your second screenshot it cannot detect your Dart version, so my guess is you don't have it installed in c:\tools. Download a separate dart sdk from here: https://dart.dev/get-dart or here https://dart.dev/get-dart/archive unzip it and update that sdk path to where you unzipped it.

Comment: Okay, so my Dart SDK was somehow missing (or perhaps I just couldn't find it in my files) so I used your link to download Dart SDK and I put it in a recognizable folder and fixed the directory issue; I gave it the right directory but unfortunately none of the project types matched what was in the tutorial. So I tried creating new Flutter projects like another user said here and somehow I created the right one and it worked - my new project matches the tutorial one and my issue's been solved. Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue and followed following steps to resolve and I hope it'll help for someone else too.

- Download Flutter SDK
- Install Flutter and Dart plugin then restart the Android studio
- Set flutter SDK path in android studio(you can set while creating new flutter project)
- Open any previous flutter project (download any open source project from gitHub if you don't have any)
- When you open old project there will be popup for dart not configured
- Click on Dart setting button from that popup
- Set dart path and allow enable dart for same project
  [image]

Method 2:
Set Dart SDK path.

- Create new flutter project
- select Dart and set dart SDK path
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

A bit late answer but it happened to me that Android Studio did create the project structure successfully, but the view was wrong so I did not see the Flutter struture files like main.dart.

In my case it was using the Android view, so I didn't see the whole structure. Be sure it uses the "Project" view.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

1. Make sure that you have installed and configured Dart & Flutter SDK
   (You can check this by running the following command in Command
   Prompt- Administrator: `flutter doctor`).
2. Then make sure the Flutter project type is selected When creating a
   new project, make sure you select the correct project type. In
   Android Studio, choose "Flutter" as the project type, not "Android."
   This ensures that Dart language support is available for your
   project.
3. If that doesn't work Sometimes, Android Studio cache can cause
   unexpected behavior. Try clearing the cache by going to "File" >
   "Invalidate Caches / Restart" and then select "Invalidate and
   Restart." This will clear the cache and restart Android Studio.

Comment: Flutter Doctor always showed me that all criteria were checked. 

I looked back here and read this part of your comment after trying the Dart path several times with no luck and so I went back to Flutter. Even though it told me in the creation process that Kotlin and Swift would be used, it still loaded with Dart and I came up with the right project template - same one I saw in the tutorial. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score -2):

Open new project with Flutter. I think Dart is already there. Try to run the default flutter app. It should work.

Comment: I reinstalled the Flutter plugin several times and manually set the directory in Android Studio and as a result something changed the plugin appearance upon starting a project. Though now I still ended up selecting Kotlin and Swift as langs upon project creation even though I was expecting to use Dart. Regardless, when opening the project I found it matched the one shown in the tutorial series I'm watching so thank you for your help!